# how to check on svn-update and build dependencies before building the actual job?

Tags: svn, maven, build, jenkins

maven project structure example, with a build-job for each project within jenkins:

```
+ project-base
  + project-common
    - sub-project-1
    - sub-project-2
```

what did I overlook if (with settings for checking the svn-repository every x minutes) the build-job for project `sub-project-2` should check `project-common` and `project-base` for updates, and build them if necessary, before the current job (which had the svn-update).

so, best case: only changes within `sub-project-2`, thus only that will be build. in case of a change in `project-base` too, that should be build first (since everything depending on `project-base` has to be build -> everything will be build in that case).

maybe it is just wrong to use the svn-check every x minutes. but since there can be updates on the code at any time, I think it is up to jenkins for blocking and building everything necessary at once. Is it or is it better to use f.e. svn polling?

Comment: Based on that structure, is it safe to assume that project-common's parent pom is project-base, and sub-project-1/2 have a parent pom of project-common?  If that's the case, you're probably thinking about this wrong in that you only have one project, which is project-base, a multi-module project.  You didn't post your svn structure, if you did, that'd help clarify this a little.

Comment: hm, sorry, its just an example, lets say, that they are parent projects `project-base` and `project-common` nontheless the svn-structure is flat. they are all projects for themselves to make it possible to pack any desired projects into a war in the end.